# Order Statistics and pdfs questions

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables, conditional-probability, order-statistics

Sorry if this looks stupid, I'm currently trying to pick up statistics and i can't understand pdfs in Order Statistics, i got several questions regarding the concepts and definitions:

1. Order Statistics reorder Y1,Y2,Y3,Y4...Yn,

Then the book tries to talk about getting pdfs for Minimum and maximum.

How can one single value have a probability distribution function(pdf)?

2. And the derivation of the theorem,
   I understand how they got to
   P(Y1<y)·P(Y2<y)...P(Yn<y)
   In the previous steps.

But then why are they suddenly show
[proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGZgr.jpg)

Again, why each single value has a cdf?

I've been reading without major problems till this chapter and then feel like i am suddenly dragged into the fourth dimension in Order Statistics.

I'm going crazy cause of all the concepts. Please if someone could help me i would be truly grateful.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Each $Y_i$ is a random variable, with its own PDF and CDF. In this case the $Y_i$ are i.i.d. so they each have the same PDF/CDF. The minimum and maximum of the $Y_i$ are also random variables, so they also have their own PDF and CDF.

Comment: PS: **pdf** stands for *probability **density** function*.